# Compiling with non primary libc,(i.e eglibc,uClibc)

Tags: linux, gcc, arm, glibc, uclibc

I am working in an embedded environment. I have a cross compiler for ARM architecture with `eglibc` as it's primary library (ie. the default `libc` coming along with the tool chain). Now I want some of the applications to link with `uClibc`. So I compiled `uClibc` with that tool-chain. Now while trying to compile and link the application with `uClibc`, there is an error. It is getting linked with the default library of the tool-chain. I think its is possible to have two different libcs on the same machine (eg. libc, uClibc).

I searched on the net and came with the following

1. [Multiple glibc libraries on a single host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host)

   As it suggested, I did the following

   ```
   $arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc -c test.c -o TEST

   $arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc TEST -o dynamic_test_with_new_opts -Wl,rpath=/home/user/UCLIBC/uClibc-0.9.32.1/INSTALL-DIR/usr/arm-linux-uclibc/lib -Wl,-dynamic-linker=/home/user/UCLIBC/uClibc-0.9.32.1/INSTALL-DIR/usr/arm-linux-uclibc/lib/ld-uClibc.so.0
   ```

   In this case, it is getting linked with the default `libc.so.6` of `eglibc`
2. [How to link to a different libc file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728552/link-to-a-different-libc-file)

   As the above link suggested, I even tried the following:

   ```
   $arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc -Xlinker -rpath=/home/user/UCLIBC/uClibc-0.9.32.1/INSTALL-DIR/usr/arm-linux-uclibc/lib -Xlinker -I/home/user/UCLIBC/uClibc-0.9.32.1/INSTALL-DIR/usr/arm-linux-uclibc/lib/ld-uClibc-0.9.32.1.so test.c -o  dynamic_test_with_linker_options
   ```

   In this case too, it is getting linked with the default `libc.so.6` of `eglibc`

Where am I going wrong? I am really stuck in this. Can someone please shed some light?

Answer (score 2):

You need to rebuild the compiler to do that, I think. The compiler needs to be configured differently to use uClibc.

Comment: Would you clarify for the sake of completeness how one can tell to compiler/linker where to look for libraries **by default**? Any link? I'm using [musl-cross](https://github.com/GregorR/musl-cross) but can't figure out how to use something else but `/lib` as default. What options shall I pass while building gcc?

Comment: You can mess with the specs file, but that's a topic for another question. This question is about one compiler targetting both Glibc and uClibc.