# Using an alternative libc in a cmake project

Tags: c++, cmake, libc, uclibc, musl

I have a C/C++ project that is built using CMake. While trying to compile a static binary, I've run into issues with different `GLIBC` versions on my computer and the target machine. In a different question on SO, the accepted answer to a similar problem is to use an alternative implementation of the libc, like `musl` or `uClibc`. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304531/compiling-with-static-libgcc-static-libstdc-still-results-in-dynamic-depende))

I can't find any information on how to point `cmake` to using such an alternative libc. Neither is a `FindMusl.cmake` file shipped, nor can I find one on the internet. Simply using `CC=/usr/bin/musl-gcc` does not work.

How can I link my cmake project statically against such alternative libc implementations, making it independent from GLIBC?

Comment: Adjust the CFLAGS and the linker flags?! Maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728552/how-to-link-to-a-different-libc-file

Answer (score 3):

To use musl library with cmake, use something like this:

```sh
export CC="musl-gcc"
cmake -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="-static -Os" ..
make
```

or

```sh
export CC="musl-gcc"
cmake -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-static -Os" ..
make
```

or

```sh
export CC="musl-gcc -static -Os"
cmake ..
make
```

Comment: not working: "Manually-specified variables were not used by the project"

Answer (score 0):

This worked better for me:

```
 cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${POLLY_ROOT}/gcc-static.cmake ..
```

[source](https://github.com/ruslo/polly)