# Need to Build for i586 target with GCC 5.3 i686 Host Toolchain

Tags: gcc, compilation, cross-compiling, i386, mmx

I need to build for an i586 target (no MMX instructions) using GCC 5.3 within a i686 host environment (32 bit Ubuntu Docker container).  The host toolchain is i686.  Is there anyway to do this without building a i586 cross-compiler ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can tell gcc to generate instructions for a particular machine type by specifying the `-march=cpu-type` option. See [x86 Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/x86-Options.html#x86-Options) in gcc documentation. So you would need something like this:

```
g++ -march=i586 [...]
```

Comment: Tried that.  The generated binary still would not work on the target.  Compiled a static binary also and it definitely contained MMX instructions most likely from glibc.

Comment: I believe you have to link against the libc version (or a smaller one) that is installed on the target machine. I would try to compile the old libc version on your build system (again using -march=i586), and link against that. maybe this helps: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728552/how-to-link-to-a-different-libc-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728552/how-to-link-to-a-different-libc-file)