# How can I cross-compile for Solaris with cgo?

Tags: c, go, gcc, solaris, cgo

I am trying to compile some [cgo](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/cgo) code for Solaris. I get these errors when I try to build:

```
$ CGO_LDFLAGS="-L$(pwd)/solaris-11.4-amd64-libs" CGO_CFLAGS='-I/home/shane/src/ioctl-experimentation/solaris-11.4-headers -Wno-unknown-pragmas' CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=solaris GOARCH=amd64 go build
# runtime/cgo
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `__libc_csu_fini'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `__libc_csu_init'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `__libc_start_main'
/usr/bin/ld: $WORK/b003/_x003.o: in function `_cgo_release_context':
gcc_context.c:(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'
/usr/bin/ld: $WORK/b003/_x004.o: in function `x_cgo_sys_thread_create':
gcc_libinit.c:(.text+0x87): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'
/usr/bin/ld: $WORK/b003/_x004.o: in function `_cgo_wait_runtime_init_done':
gcc_libinit.c:(.text+0x121): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'
/usr/bin/ld: $WORK/b003/_x004.o: in function `_cgo_try_pthread_create':
gcc_libinit.c:(.text+0x291): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'
/usr/bin/ld: $WORK/b003/_x006.o: in function `x_cgo_init':
gcc_solaris_amd64.c:(.text+0xb6): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'
/usr/bin/ld: $WORK/b003/_x006.o:gcc_solaris_amd64.c:(.text+0x214): more undefined references to `__stack_chk_fail' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am cross-compiling on Linux. Here is my Go version:

```
$ go version
go version go1.18.3 linux/amd64
```

The `solaris-11.4-amd64-libs` directory contains a copy of all files under `/lib/amd64` from a Solaris 11.4 AMD64 machine. The `solaris-11.4-headers` directory contains a copy of all files under `/usr/include` from a Solaris 11.4 AMD64 machine.

Here is my Go code in `main.go`:

```
//go:build solaris
// +build solaris

package main

import "C"

func main() {
}
```

I know [cgo is fully supported for Solaris as of Go 1.5](https://go.dev/doc/go1.5#ports), and I am using Go 1.18.

I'm looking for help understanding why these linker errors are happening, even when I copied across all libs from the `/lib/amd64` directory. Is it possible there are more libs I also need to copy over from somewhere else?

**Edit**

At the suggestion of Liam Kelly, I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728552/how-to-link-to-a-different-libc-file) about how to link against a different libc. I tried passing `-Xlinker -rpath=$(pwd)/solaris-11.4-amd64-libs` as part of `CGO_LDFLAGS`, but I got the same errors as before. I tried using `-nodefaultlibs` and `-nostdlib` both separately and together along with `-Xlinker -rpath=$(pwd)/solaris-11.4-amd64-libs`, but using either of these two flags either separately or together just increased the number of linker errors.

Comment: Which symbols are undefined if you leave out the `-lxnet` library?

Comment: I never specify the `-lxnet` library myself, it is automatically used by `go build`. I don't know how to prevent `go build` from passing this flag to `gcc`.

Comment: It doesn’t matter if there’s an equivalent for Linux, you need the Solaris libraries (well, at least the headers) to build for Solaris. Figure out what it takes to cross compile general C code, and it’s the same for using CGO

Comment: @JimB, please see my updated question. Even with the Solaris libraries and headers copied over from a Solaris machine, cross-compiling from my Linux host fails with several linker errors.

Comment: @ShaneBishop what is your host OS? the easiest way forward is to use a gcc version that is already hardcoded with solaris parameters (IE:  `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` for windows)

Comment: @LiamKelly, my host OS that I am cross-compiling on is Linux (specifically Ubuntu). I would assume that the `go build` tool would automatically use the appropriate compiler when I use `GOOS=solaris`, am I wrong? Also, I don't believe I have any `*-solaris*-gcc` on my Linux system.

Comment: @ShaneBishop just to clarify, are you compiling for a SPARC or Solaris running on a typical AMD64 platform?

Comment: @LiamKelly I am compiling for Solaris AMD64. You can see this from what I set as the `GOOS` and `GOARCH` in my `go build` command at the top of my question.

Comment: @ShaneBishop I think you are going to need to link against the Solaris libc not the gnu libc for the c portion of code to work. Basically trying some of the techniques metioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728552/how-to-link-to-a-different-libc-file.

Comment: @LiamKelly, I tried the suggestions for both answers in that question, but I continued to get linker errors. See my edit for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that `libxnet` is needed for Solaris and that is why is is being automatically added.

First confirm that the libxnet library is where is should be with `sudo find /lib libxnet*`. I expect you will see one line of the output show:

`lib/64/libxnet.so`

Assuming you see the above output, I believe you just need to tell the linker to look in that location with `CGO_LDFLAGS="-L/lib/64" CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=solaris GOARCH=amd64 go build`. If that works then you should be able to embedded that LDFlag in your `main.go` file with:

```golang
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L/lib/64
import "C"
```

Once embedded you will not need to explicitly set `CGO_LDFLAGS`

Comment: Please see my updated question. I copied the `libxnet.so` file from a Solaris machine to my host Linux machine that I am cross-compiling on. For some reason, my `#cgo` directive is being ignored.

Comment: Actually, in my new update to my question, I left out the `#cgo` directive for now, and instead I just use `CGO_LDFLAGS`.